# Type definition of Promise.all doesn't match with the docs

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Looking at [the type definition of `Promise.all`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L41), I see 10 definitions:

```
/**
 * Creates a Promise that is resolved with an array of results when all of the provided Promises
 * resolve, or rejected when any Promise is rejected.
 * @param values An array of Promises.
 * @returns A new Promise.
 */
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
```

I only included the one with an array of length 3, but there also exist `all<T1>`, `all<T1, T2>`, all the way up to `all<T1, T2, ..., T9, T10>`.

However, this doesn't match with the implementation of `Promise.all`, which can take as an input an array longer than 10:

```js
let myPromise = num => Promise.resolve(num);
let myPromisesArray = (new Array(20))
  .fill()
  .map((_,i) => myPromise(i));
Promise.all(myPromisesArray).then(console.log)
```

I'm not the worst developer in the world but still, I make the assumption that the Microsoft developers who produced the type definition of ES2015 know more about JS/TS than me, which begs the question:

> Why the type definition of Promise.all doesn't match with neither [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) nor its implementation?

Comment: I guess they don't want to write `all` for infinite values. That would be a lot of typing.

Comment: Oh okay, so the limitation is that TypeScript cannot type every element of an array?

Comment: It could, given enough time and a big enough hard drive to write all types out. The last declaration, `all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;`, takes an array with unlimited size tough. Its just limited to use only a single type in the array. All other declarations take different types.

Comment: I never used `Promise.all` with a mixed type array with more than two or three elements ... and I wrote some JS already ... so there are actually very very rare usecases for `Promise.all` with 10+ different types, and in that case you can just add your own typings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic declaration up to 10 types is only accounting for non-uniform "tuples", or arrays where different indices have explicit independent types.

There is also [a declaration that supports a uniformly typed array](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L113) of unbounded length:

```
all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

The declarations using a tuple of up to length 10 are supposed to cover a reasonable amount of use-cases, and are due to a limitation of TypeScript as a language, since generic type inference for a tuple is a uniform array of an encompassing [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), which would use the signature above. These sort of generic declarations up to an arbitrary bound of non-homogeneous types are common-place in other langauges like C# as well. For example, [`Action<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Func<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) use a limit of 16 parameter types.

Comment: A generic type list would be fun, however the usecases are probably very rare ...