# Typescript .bind() gives type error when using more than 4 parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using typescript 3.5.2 I have encountered a problem related with `.bind()`.

I am trying to bind a function with some initial parameters.

```
async foo(arg1: any,
    arg2: any,
    arg3: any,
    arg4: any,
    arg5: any,
    arg6: any,
    arg7: any) {
    //some fancy tasks
}
```

I am trying to bind the function with a context and some initial paramaters.

```
private buildHandler(arg1: Function, arg2: IReplaceSet[], arg3: IReplaceSet[] = [], arg4: IReplaceAsset[] = [], arg5: boolean) {
    return this.foo.bind(this, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
}
```

Typescript resolves `.bind` as this type.

```
bind<T, AX, R>(this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
```

And the error compiler gives:

> return this.foo.bind(this, arg1, (error)arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
>
> Error:(401, 64) TS2345: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'.
>     Type 'IReplaceSet[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 4 more.

---

Edit1:
Whenever I remove any of these initial parameters from bind errors fixes

```
return this.foo.bind(this, arg1, arg2, arg3, ag4);
```

Why there is a parameter limit on typescript .bind() definition? Because it matches the type

```
bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
```

---

Edit2:
Spreading also fixes the problem but why?

```
return this.foo.bind(this, ...[arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5]);
```

---

Edit3:
Now I am thinking that this is a typescript related issue and I solved the problem. I will submit an answer to this because it is an important issue.

Comment: `this` should represent an object and not a function like in this interface `(this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R`

Comment: @Rajesh Please see my edit, it works well with 4 initial paramaters.

Comment: Related: [Type definition of Promise.all doesn't handle more than 10 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637404/type-definition-of-promise-all-doesnt-match-with-the-docs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript `CallableFunction` interface with `bind` method supports at most 4 parameters with unique type definitions.

```
interface CallableFunction extends Function {
    bind < T > (this: T, thisArg: ThisParameterType < T > ): OmitThisParameter < T > ;
    bind < T, A0, A extends any[], R > (this: (this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0): (...args: A) => R;
    bind < T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R > (this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, th
isArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): (...args: A) => R;
    bind < T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R > (this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): (...args: A) => R;
    bind < T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R > (this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
    bind < T, AX, R > (this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
}
```

As you can see the `bind(context, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` is supported with the type:

```
bind < T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R > (this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
```

But whenever you use more than 4 initial parameters it will use this type:

```
bind < T, AX, R > (this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
```

And this type expects all initial arguments to be generic type `AX` which means: all the parameters you will use should be the same type as your first parameter. To give an example:

This will give an error. Because the type of arg4 is not same as arg1

```
arg1: string;
arg2: string;
arg3: string;
arg4: number;
arg5: string;
arg6: string;
bind(context, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
```

Spreading solved my issue because spreading doesn't have any type definitions on typescript yet.

I hope it helps for others too.

Comment: It looks like spreading has type definitions now, so that's not working anymore unfortunately :(